# Certificate validation .net standard 2.1 running on linux

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am working on application on `.net standard 2.1`. For the http client I am using `HttpWebRequest` and in one point we had to make a custom certificate validation using the callback `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` Property.
On Windows Os we add the certificate in CA store and the validation works properly by building the chain of certificates `X509Chain` in the callback
`public delegate bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate? certificate, X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors);`. My first question is where should I add the certificate on linux so the validation works?
Apart from that is it a way to add the certificate without installing it by providing maybe the path ?

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is where should I add the certificate on linux so the validation works?

To trust a certificate on Linux you can either add it to your system trust collection (instructions depends on your distro), or you can add it to the `CurrentUser\Root` `X509Store` (which is managed by .NET and doesn't influence system tools like `curl`).

> Apart from that is it a way to add the certificate without installing it by providing maybe the path?

.NET 5 added a feature to X509Chain which allows for specifying the set of trusted root stores for a specific chain build.  If you're using .NET 5+ you could reconfigure the X509Chain instance that's provided to switch it to custom trust and specify your certificate that way.  (For .NET 7 we're hoping to make it easier to specify this as an input to SslStream/HttpClient so that you don't have to wait until the callback and throw away the first chain build.)

> I am working on application on .net standard 2.1.

FWIW: You can't have a .NET Standard application, because .NET Standard is a set of types and members with no associated runtime.  .NET Core 3.0+ (including .NET 5+), and apparently some Xamarin and Unity workloads implement .NET Standard 2.1... and your application would be for one of them (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to ask what could be the path for the `CurrentUser\Root X509Store` on mac os. Maybe installing the certificate in the ca store would be enough similar to windows. Indeed the framework that the mac is using .net core 2.0 which looks like old one. So your suggestion is to update the version to .net core 5 + and use the X509Chain feature to build the chain by providing the certificate ?

Comment: `using X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadWrite); store.Add(cert);`,  Only the programmatic model is supported.

Comment: Is there a location to add the certificate similar to windows ca store?

Comment: @AlexandrosMor `new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)`, same as on Windows.